# Error in reverse of string as the way i want to make this code useful is not working can olyone sort this out

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
a=input("Enter a line ")
b=a.split()
j=b
print(b)
c=int(len(b))
print(c)
for i in range(c):
    print(i,-(i+1))
    j[i]=b[-(i+1)]
    print(j[i],b[-(i+1)])
print(j)
print(b)
r=" ".join(j)
print(r)
```

why there is error in this code like everytime a input some line to reverse it the result is not showing in the reverse order

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please show a sample of the unexpected output you are getting.

Comment: I want to reverse the word order

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to reverse the word order, you can do it like this:

```py
def reverse_word_order(line):
    parts = line.split()
    return ' '.join(parts[::-1])

print(reverse_word_order(input('Enter a line:')))
```